# multiple generic overloads

Tags: c#, generics

I have a simple helper class that I use to build a simple comma separated string.

```
private string AddcsvString(string s)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Value))
    {
        return s;
    }
    else
    {
        return this.Value + "," + s;
    }
}
```

I also have a generic method that calls this

```
public void Add<T>(T s) where T: struct 
{
     this.Value = AddcsvString(s.ToString());
}
```

I wanted to add an overload for a generic List

```
public void Add<T>(IEnumerable<T> values)where T:struct 
{
    foreach (T t in values)
    {
        Add(t.ToString());
    }
}
```

But any attempt to call this called the first generic method. So I ended up renaming the second generic method to AddAll.  In the end I think this was the right way to go for this case but would like to know if it is possible to have both for future reference.

--edit 
Here is the case that doesn't work

```
CsvString test = new CsvString();
string result;
test.Add(1);
test.Add('2');
test.Add("3");
result = test.ToString();  //  result = "1,2,3"

CsvString test2 = new CsvString();
List<long> aList = new List<long>();
string result2;
aList.Add(1);
aList.Add(2);
aList.Add(3);
test2.Add(aList);  //line doesn't compile
```

--edit 2 
I found a second solution (though JoshE below gets credit for answering this, thanks btw).
I changed the second method to this

```
public SWcsvString Add<T,K>(T values)where T: IEnumerable<K> where K: struct
{
    foreach (K k in values)
    {
        Add(k.ToString());
    }
    return this;
}
```

and the call to this

```
test2.Add<IEnumerable<long>,long>(aList);
```

Comment: What problem you got? How you call the first generic method?

Comment: How are you calling your methods? Just tested the case and works fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing your constraints `where T : struct`, and I think you will get the proper behavior.

`IEnumerable<char> <==> String`, since a `string` is just a `char[]`. Since a `string` is not *really* a value-object, overload resolution will almost always favor the first method to avoid the boxing/unboxing operation of converting a string to `IEnumerable<char>`. (I'm guessing that you've tried calling it with both `"foo"` and `IEnumerable<bar>` where `bar` is a struct).

Comment: the `where T : struct` prevents calling the method with a type that I don't trust the `toString()` method. Avoid 'toString()' results like System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int64]

Comment: why would you have reason to distrust `.ToString()`? You can have the same issue you cite with a struct as with a value type.

Comment: if you only want to consider primitives with your method, you can use reflection to check whether or not `T` implements `.ToString()` as opposed to using `Object.ToString()`. You could also check whether a particular arg is of type IEnumerable and respond appropriately.

Comment: Good point Josh I had read that `where T: struct` was the best way to restrict to primitives didn't occur to me that `struct foo{ int a; }` would match.  So it seems my compile time check wasn't as strong as I thought.  The reflection check is an interesting idea but wouldn't want to make that check at run time, it should happen at compile time (stop me from making a bad call before it happens).

Comment: Checking for the existence of an overridden `ToString` is a cheap operation, even if it does involve reflection, its an inherently lazy operation since it can break as soon as an override is found, or it gets to Object

Comment: it's not really a question of cpu time (and your right it would be a cheap operation) it's a matter of when an error is found.  If it's found at compile time it's impossible for a user to ever have an issue (assuming you don't release code that doesn't build), if it's a run time error you must rely on testing to find any bug before the user

Comment: that's why we write unit tests - to catch issues near build time that normally would only be caught at run-time